# How to concatenate multiple array elements when the arrays have different number of elements?

Tags: swift

This is my first time coding in Swift. Title

```
var licensep1 = ["A","B","C", "E", "U", "D", "T", "R"]
var licensep2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
var licensep3 = ["H", "Z", "F", "W", "G", "H", "I", "K"]
for i in stride(from: 0, to: licensep1.count, by: 1) {
    print(licensep1[i] + licensep2[i] + licensep3[i] + " " + licensep1[i + 1] + licensep2[i + 1] + licensep3[i + 1])
}
```

I'm basically trying to make random license plates that have 6 alphanumerics each and I'm trying to use only those 5 numbers you see in "licensep2". How would you re-loop through the 5 numbers again once it has reached the last number while continuing the original loop for the letters ? I hope my question is clear

It currently outputs this:

- A1H B2Z
- B2Z C3F
- C3F E4W
- E4W U5G

but I'd like it to continue to output until licensep1 reaches "R", reusing the numbers.

Comment: Where is the random part?

Answer (score 1):

The most dumb approach would be simply to pad `licensep2` array to make it the same length as the others, so instead of

```
var licensep2 = ["1", "2", "3", "6", "9"]
```

you will have to make it look like this:

```
var licensep2 = ["1", "2", "3", "6", "9", "1", "2", "3"]
```

Better, smarter approach would be use modulo (`%`) on index used to pick items from array (modulo by array length of course). So during concatenation:

```
... + licensep2[i % licensep2.count] + ...
```

also this part of concatenation:

```
licensep1[i + 1]
```

should perhaps be

```
licensep1[i]
```

otherwise you will fail reaching outside of bounds of your array at the last iteration of your loop. Or modulo this as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use the magic remainder (or "modulo") operator:

```
var licensep1 = ["A","B","C", "E", "U", "D", "T", "R"]
var licensep2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
var licensep3 = ["H", "Z", "F", "W", "G", "H", "I", "K"]
for i in stride(from: 0, to: licensep1.count, by: 1) {
    print(licensep1[i] + licensep2[i % 5] + licensep3[i] + " " + licensep1[i + 1] + licensep2[(i + 1) % 5] + licensep3[i + 1])
}
```

Note: you're going to get an `index out of range` error given this current loop, though. Add code to ensure your `i + 1` values don't exceed the length of the `licensep1` and `licensep3` arrays!

The remainder operator allows you to restart a count once it reaches a certain value. For example:

```
i == 0    i % 5 = 0
i == 1    i % 5 = 1
i == 2    i % 5 = 2
i == 3    i % 5 = 3
i == 4    i % 5 = 4
i == 5    i % 5 = 0
i == 6    i % 5 = 1
... and so on.
```

Your remainder will always be between 0 and 4 (thus covering the 5 possible values in your `licensep2` array).